# Updating Deployment.yaml for Argo CD: How to Edit and Change Image Tag Version in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have an Azure pipeline to build the source code and create a Docker image for deployment.

As part of my pipeline, I need to edit a specific deployment.yaml file in my repository with a new build image tag value. This enables my ArgoCD to pick up the manifest file and deploy it to the Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the manifest **`deployment.yml`** has the content like as below. Here we need to use the actual value of a new image tag to replace the placeholder token **`{{image_tag}}`**.

```yaml
. . .
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: briranacr 
          image: briranacr.azurecr.io/mainfuncapp:{{image_tag}}
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

And in the pipeline, we use the pipeline variable **`$(image_tag)`** to get/pass the value of new image tag.

Here we can use any of the following ways to update the image tag in the manifest **`deployment.yml`** file.

1. Use the **`sed`** command to replace the placeholder token.

   ```yaml
   - bash: 'sed -i -e ''s/{{image_tag}}/$(image_tag)/g'' manifest/deployment.yml'
     displayName: 'Replace Token'
   ```

   [image]
2. Use the pipeline task provided by the extension "[**Replace Tokens**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_signedin?reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3Dqetza.replacetokens%26targetId%3De798dfe9-efa6-4ece-a142-e9ed554e4ebf%26utm_source%3Dvstsproduct%26utm_medium%3DExtHubManageList)".

   ```yaml
   - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
     displayName: 'Replace Token'
     inputs:
       targetFiles: manifest/deployment.yml
       tokenPattern: doublebraces
       keepToken: true
       actionOnNoFiles: warn
   ```

   **Note:** When using this task, ensure the name of the placeholder token is same as that of the pipeline variable. For example, the '**`image_tag`**' in this sample.

   [image]

---